# Kubernetes pods scaling doesnt increase throughput

Tags: kubernetes, load-balance, performance

I have a simple Django web application running on AWS EC2 instance (2 vCPU, 4Gi).
For that type of deployment I have a performance (measured with [Hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey))

```
$ hey -t 30 -z 1m https://mydomain.com/my/endpoint/
```

about `30 reqs/s`

When deployed with Kubernetes onto EKS cluster (same docker image) I have about `15 reqs/s` for 1 pod with limits

```
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "500m"
        memory: "2Gi"
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: "4Gi"
```

I expect that scaling pods would double the performance but nothing happens (request rate stays the same)

```
$ kubectl scale deploy/myapp --replicas=2
```

I'm running Django app behind `gunicorn` like this (adjusting number of workers did not help)

```
gunicorn --config gunicorn.py myapp.wsgi:application
# gunicorn.py
import os

# tried different values from 1 to 5
# for 1 vCPU allocated for the pod it should be 3 as per docs
# (2 x $num_cores) + 1
# https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers
workers = int(os.getenv('GUNICORN_WORKERS_APP', default=4))
daemon = False
bind = '0.0.0.0:8080'
max_requests = 2000
```

So couple of questions here:

- how to properly debug this type of issue and what's the toolset I can use?
- how `service` does load balancing to pods and is there any overhead introduced?
- is there an overhead for resource management (cpu allocation/throttling)?
- how performance tuning is done for k8s-driven applications?

Comment: An APM like New Relic would be a tool to see the pods load and response times.
How services do load balancing is provided here:-https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies

There could be some overhead but not such that two pods provide the same i/o as one.

Could you check if there could be other factors like ingress-controller configurations and such?

Answer (score 1):

What does 'kubectl top node' return for your node usage?

Kubernetes is pretty low overhead and can certainly handle more than 15req/s. Does your application rely on a database? If so, where is that database living? Is that single node also running any other pods?

As others noted, an APM would be a helpful tool to diagnose unexpected performance issues.